# lineChartView findViewById in fragment

Tags: java, android, charts

i have some errors when i try to add chart in fragment. 
i'm trying to make a chart in a fragment which will refer to the `LineChartView` element which I have created in XML for the Fragment.

I use hellochart and I read the tutorial. explained there using activity to implement it. how do i implement it to fragment?

```java
LineChartView lineChartView;
String[] axisData = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept",
            "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
int[] yAxisData = {50, 20, 15, 30, 20, 60, 15, 40, 45, 10, 90, 18};
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lineChartView = findViewById(R.id.chart);
        List yAxisValues = new ArrayList();
        List axisValues = new ArrayList();
        Line line = new Line(yAxisValues).setColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));
        for (int i = 0; i < axisData.length; i++) {
            axisValues.add(i, new AxisValue(i).setLabel(axisData[i]));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < yAxisData.length; i++) {
            yAxisValues.add(new PointValue(i, yAxisData[i]));
        }
        List lines = new ArrayList();
        lines.add(line);
        LineChartData data = new LineChartData();
        data.setLines(lines);
        Axis axis = new Axis();
        axis.setValues(axisValues);
        axis.setTextSize(16);
        axis.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
        data.setAxisXBottom(axis);
        Axis yAxis = new Axis();
        yAxis.setName("Sales in millions");
        yAxis.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
        yAxis.setTextSize(16);
        data.setAxisYLeft(yAxis);
        lineChartView.setLineChartData(data);
        Viewport viewport = new Viewport(lineChartView.getMaximumViewport());
        viewport.top = 110;
        lineChartView.setMaximumViewport(viewport);
        lineChartView.setCurrentViewport(viewport);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);
    }
```

The findViewById method has an error on it which states that the method is cannot resolve.

Comment: see for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `onCreateView` on this and tell me if it works.
First declare `View`

```
private View paramView;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);
  lineChartView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
  // Here comes all your code
  return paramView;
}
```

Comment: @AsyiqM glad to help can you make upvote my answer.